# Function List in C++ file in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way or a plugin in Notepad++ which lists out all the functions present in a C++ file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin called **Function List** found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Function%20List/)